# Check if user input matches answer to sum of 2 random Numbers

Tags: java, random

---

Hi Im trying to generate 2 random numbers, add them together and have the user input match the answer, it works for lower numbers in the range(0-50) but not for higher numbers. Im relatively new to programming so any help would be great. Thanks in advance

```
static int randomNum(){
Random numR = new Random();
int randomNum = numR.nextInt(51);

return randomNum;
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1 =randomNum();
    int num2 =randomNum();
    int answer =num1+num2;
    
   
    System.out.println("What is "+num1+"+"+num2+" equal to?");
    if (sc.hasNextInt(answer))
        System.out.println("Correct");
    else
        System.out.println("Wrong");
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasNextInt(someInt)`, which is what you're invoking, treats the argument as **the radix**, totally not what you want. Even if it did what you wanted, it wouldn't consume the input - it's `hasNextInt`, not `consumeNextInt`.

You want to call `sc.nextInt()`, and then compare what that returned with answer.

Comment: Whoops...I think you placed this comment under the wrong post @cliff2310.

Comment: Yes sorry, I scrolled down to far ....